# Populating dropdown using Laravel Eloquent and DB

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm on Laravel and Eloquent, and trying to populate a view's dropdown box with results of a select query.

In my controller:

```
public function uploadDocs($userid)
{
    $doc_options = DB::select('select document.document_description from document where user_id = ?', array($userid));

    return View::make('uploaddocs')->with('doc_options', $doc_options);
}
```

In my view:

```
<body>
{{ Form::select('doc_options_id', $doc_options) }}
</body>
```

I'm getting the following stack trace:

```
htmlentities() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given (View: /home/vagrant/code/eduview/app/views/uploaddocs.blade.php)
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$doc_options = DB::statement(DB::raw('select document.document_description from document where user_id = ?', array($userid)))->get();`

Edit: I should probably explain first.

`DB::select()` is primarily used for the database builder in order to chain onto other chain-able functions, and not for doing your whole query.

You could use `DB::statement` to provide a new custom SQL query in it, but you also have to specify that the contents of the statement()'s parameter will be a raw query. Hence the `DB::raw`

Alternatively you could take advantage of Eloquent or Laravel's query builder by creating an Eloquent model called `Document` in `app/models` with contents as:

`class Document extends Eloquent {}`

and swap out your query above with:

`$doc_options = Document::select('document_description')->where('user_id','=',$userid)->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an object into the `Form::select()` helper, and it is expecting an array.

Instead, Laravel has tools built in to do just this. See the `lists()` method in the Laravel docs under [Selects](http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects):

```
public function uploadDocs($userid)
{
    $doc_options = DB::table('document')->where('user_id', $userid)->lists('document_description');

    return View::make('uploaddocs')->with('doc_options', $doc_options);
}
```

That should be it.